# $a+\frac{1}{a}\ge 2$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}_{+}$

Tags: inequality

This inequality is more than obvious:
$$a+\frac{1}{a}\ge 2
$$ 
But my question is: is this only a special case of some "bigger" lemma (like e.g. $\frac{a+b}{2}\ge\sqrt{ab}$ is a special ase of the AM-GM inequality)?

Comment: It is a case of AM-GM, after you divide by $2$: $\sqrt{a\cdot\frac{1}{a}}$.

Comment: But the AM-GM inequality also follows from a square being non-negative.

Answer (score 6):

$$
a+\frac{1}{a}\ge 2\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \frac{a^2-2a+1}{a}\ge 0
\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \frac{(a-1)^2}{a}\ge 0.
$$

Answer (score 5):

Well, you can let $b=\frac{1}{a}$ in $a + b \geq 2\sqrt{ab}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  It follows as a consequence of $x^2 \geq 0$ for all real numbers $x$.

Can you take it from here?